# Creating a multi-level pipe for Linux commands

Tags: c, unix, command-line, pipe

I'm trying to create a multi-level pipe, where the input is Linux commands (e.g. ls | sort) and the output is just the regular output when typed into a Linux console (essentially just use execlp to execute the commands).

I've attempted to create a program that works for 1 and 2 levels, but I can't seem to get the 2 level one to work, specifically with the command "ls | sort". The program just freezes. I also don't know how to continue beyond that and add more levels (required to support 16 total).

```
// the function has to return unless the command is "exit"
void process_cmd(char *cmdline) {
    // exit program
    if (strcmp(cmdline, "exit") == 0) {
        printf("The shell program (pid=%d) terminates\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }

    // separate the user input into the different commands using another 
    // defined function
    char* strings[MAX_PIPE_SEGMENTS];
    int x = 0;
    int* numTokens = &x;
    tokenize(strings, cmdline, numTokens, "|");

    // 1 command
    if (*numTokens == 1) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            execlp(strings[0], strings[0], NULL);
        } else {
            wait(0);
            return;
        }
    }

    // 2 commands, this is the problem
    int ps[*numTokens];
    pipe(ps);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) {
            close(1);
            dup2(ps[1], 1);
            close(ps[0]);
            execlp(strings[0], strings[0], NULL);
        } else {
            close(0);
            dup2(ps[0], 0);
            close(ps[1]);
            wait(0);
            execlp(strings[1], strings[1], NULL);
        }
    } else {
        wait(0);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere along the way you need to dup2() the ends of your pipe to stdin and stdout. I don't see a line of code where you do that, but I do see some use of dup(). Is that what you meant?

Comment: @GemTaylor I have to specifically use dup2()? I wrote dup() because in a previous homework problem (similar thing but you don't have to return, just execute) it was dup(). Basically that question just involved the code inside if(pid==0). So instead of dup(ps[1]), it's dup2(ps[1], 1)? And then instead of dup(ps[0]), it's dup2(ps[0], 0)? Or have I gotten those backwards?

Comment: dup(n) makes a new handle to the same open file, but you don't know what number you will get. dup2(n,m) makes a new handle m (but first it closes m if it is in use). In your case you want to dup the handle to stdin or stdout (0 or 1) so you definitely need dup2(). If you are /very/ lucky, because you closed handle 0 and handle 1 then dup(n)  /might/ reuse that handle, but you can't rely on that!

Comment: @GemTaylor I changed the dup() to dup2() but nothing changed.

Comment: Ok, next I would make the two processes be long-lived, like `sleep 101` and `sleep 102`, and check with top that they actually get started.

Comment: @GemTaylor How do I do that? Do I just run the program, interrupt when it freezes, and then run top? I did that and they didn't show up.

Comment: If they are working, sort and ls probably don't take very long to run. How quick are you at breaking in:-) You can either ctlz to pause, or use a second console to run top

Comment: @GemTaylor I used top in a second console and it turns out I made a mistake, they apparently run fine. I removed the sleep functions and "sort" shows up as a process (tried again and now there are just three "myshell" which is the name of the program), but it's just there with the original program still frozen.

Comment: OK, so that is the same behaviour for sort you would get if you just type sort on the commandline. why would that be?

Comment: @GemTaylor I edited that comment because now there are just three "myshell" processes which is the name of my program, I have no idea what's happening now. I assume the sort process is just running but not actually using the ls output as its input so it just freezes, but I don't know what's wrong with the pipe.

Comment: I think you need to update to show how you have used dup2

Comment: @GemTaylor Okay, I edited my post.

Comment: Ok, another very useful debug, is to look up the Process IDs, which you can either do with top, or by printf in the code. Then, you can ls -l the folder /proc/<pid>/fd . This gives you a clue how the two processes are connected by pipes Again probably you need to switch to using sleep to get time to do this.

Comment: @GemTaylor I got it but I have no idea how to interpret it. [Here's the link](https://imgur.com/a/9QmXWQq)

Comment: It tells you they are both joined to the same pipe object [99485] which is good news! And that the other stdin/stdout are to the console /dev/pts/2 - so that all looks good.

Comment: @GemTaylor Why isn't it working though?

Comment: You are still leaving file descriptors open.  Your code is `close(1); dup2(ps[1], 1); close(ps[0])`.  You need to also `close(ps[1])`

Comment: eg, the general template is: `dup2(ps[1], 1); close(ps[0]); close(ps[1])` . Close both sides of the pipe after you've dup'd.

Comment: Agh! That's what the fd folder should have told us!