# Multi-level pipes in C

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I have to create a multi-level pipe in C that interprets Linux commands just like the Unix console. The code I have works for a 2-level pipe but I have to implement more (up to 16). The main problem here is I'm not sure how to take the output of the first two commands and then reroute it to be the input of the third command (etc. for the other levels). I know I need to use "1" of the first pipe and "0" of the second pipe since those are stdout and stdin respectively but I am unsure how to implement this in practice.

```
// tokenize is a separate function that uses strtok repeatedly on cmdline, setting the array 
// segments to the strings separated by | and numTokens to the number of commands
char* segments[MAX_PIPE_SEGMENTS];
int x = 0;
int* numTokens = &x;
tokenize(segments, cmdline, numTokens, "|");

// the code for one command
if (*numTokens == 1) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        char* strings[MAX_SEGMENT_LENGTH];
        int y = 0;
        int* numStrings = &y;
        tokenize(strings, segments[0], numStrings, " ");
        execvp(strings[0], strings);
    } else {
        wait(0);
        return;
    }
}

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < *numTokens-1; i++) {
        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) {
            int ps[2];
            pipe(ps);
            pid_t pid3 = fork();
            if (pid3 == 0) {
                close(1);
                dup2(ps[1], 1);
                close(ps[0]);
                char* strings[MAX_SEGMENT_LENGTH];
                int y = 0;
                int* numStrings = &y;
                tokenize(strings, segments[i], numStrings, " ");
                execvp(strings[0], strings);
            } else {
                close(0);
                dup2(ps[0], 0);
                close(ps[1]);
                wait(0);
                char* strings[MAX_SEGMENT_LENGTH];
                int y = 0;
                int* numStrings = &y;
                tokenize(strings, segments[i+1], numStrings, " ");
                execvp(strings[0], strings);
            }
        } else {
            wait(0);
        }
    }
} else {
    wait(0);
    return;
}
```

Comment: This looks very similar to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374595 you asked yesterday.

Comment: @Bodo Yesterday I couldn't get the 2-level pipe to work, now I got it working and my code is quite different because of the loop. Now I need to get it working for more levels.

Comment: You don't have _to take the output of the first two commands and then reroute it to be the input of the third command_ - you just have _to take the output of the_ second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, treating the first and second command in different `if`/`else` blocks is not generalizable to more than two commands. Feasible is to treat the pipe commands and operations identically as far as possible and only add special conditions for the first and last:

```
    int i, in, out = dup(1);    // save standard output descriptor
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int ps[2];
        if (i < x-1) pipe(ps);  // if not last in line, make a pipe
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // if not first in line, connect standard input to pipe
            if (i) dup2(in, 0), close(in);
            // if not last in line, connect standard output to pipe
            if (i < x-1) dup2(ps[1], 1), close(ps[1]);
            // if last in line, restore standard output to original
            else dup2(out, 1), close(out);
            char* strings[MAX_SEGMENT_LENGTH];
            int y = 0;
            int* numStrings = &y;
            tokenize(strings, segments[i], numStrings, " ");
            execvp(strings[0], strings);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (i) close(in);
        close(ps[1]);
        in = ps[0]; // the current pipe's read end is the new input
    }
    close(out);
    do ; while (wait(0) > 0);
```